# Python - 2D Array: Finding Coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, logic

I have a python based battleship game that allows players to pass in a .csv containing a 10x10 grid of 0s and 1s, where 1s correspond to locations of ships. For example,

```
In [1]: board = np.genfromtext(filename, delimiter=',')
Out[2]: array([
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

(5) unit ship located at board[8,5:10]

(4) unit ship located at board[7,3:7]

(3) unit ship located at board[3:6,2]

(3) unit ship located at board[3:6,6]

(2) unit ship located at board[8:10,0]

The game restricts players to 5 ships with sizes of (5, 4, 3, 3, 2). Given this information how can I come up with a method for determining the coordinates for each ship?

I'm currently applying a for loop that finds indexes where 1s are present, see below.

```
for ri, ci in zip(range(board.shape[0]), range(board.shape[1])):
    # get row indexes of ships 
    rlocs = len(np.where(board[ri,:]==1)[0])
    # get col indexes of ships 
    clocs = len(np.where(board[:,ci]==1)[0])
    # skip empty row and col
    if (rlocs == 0) and (clocs == 0): continue 
    # check if consecutives <int>
    rcons = is_consecutive(rlocs)
    ccons = is_consecutive(clocs)
    # if more than one consecutive is found then assume more than 1 ship in row/col
    if (rcons > 1) or (ccons > 1):
        # .... ?
```

At this point I'm unsure what the next step would be... any help or advice is welcomed!

**FYI:** `is_consecutive` returns an **int** of the number of values in a list that are in a consecutive order. For example, [0,1,2,9,10] would return 2 (i.e., 0-2 and 9-10).

The **output** that I'm looking for is a dictionary that looks similar to this:

{'ship_05_01': [(x0,y0), (x1,y1)], 'ship_03_01': [(x0,y0), (x1,y1)], 'ship_03_02': [(x0,y0), (x1,y1)], ...}

where ship_xx_nn --> xx = number of spaces; nn = index

Comment: Note that there might not be a unique solution for a given input. Consider an 'L' shape that is 7 down and 6 across. This could contain (starting from the top) the two 3 ships vertically, followed by the 2 and 4 ships horizontally. Or, it could contain the 2 and 4 ships vertically, followed by the two 3 ships horizontally. Of course, it wouldn't affect the game turnout, but I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: If you're allowed to change the input format, you could use the lengths of the ships instead of 1s. So, a 3-ship would be represented by three consecutive 3s. This would make it much easier to decipher where each ship is and would resolve ambiguities.